# Can't cast my double derived class of my base class into my base class C++

Tags: c++, casting

I have an archi like that:

```
namespace nts {

   class IComponent
   {
   };

   class AbsComponent : public IComponent
   {
   };

   class cInput : public AbsComponent
   {
   };

}
```

I can't figure out how to cast a cInput as a std::unique_ptr < nts::IComponent >
i tried like this with C-style cast:

```
std::unique_ptr<nts::IComponent> createInput(const std::string &val) noexcept
  {
        std::unique_ptr<nts::IComponent> component = (std::unique_ptr<nts::IComponent>)new nts::cInput(val));
        return (component);
  }
```

How could i cast this ?

Comment: You don't need to cast to a base class.

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
std::unique_ptr<nts::IComponent> component = std::make_unique<nts::cInput>(val);
```

Also, you probably meant:

```
return component;
```

instead of:

```
return (val);
```

But you can just do:

```
return std::make_unique<nts::cInput>(val);
```

instead of the two lines.

EDIT:

`std::make_unique` is available from C++14, if you're using an older version, strongly consider updating, or you can do:

```
std::unique_ptr<nts::IComponent> component = std::unique_ptr<nts::cInput>(new nts::cInput(val));
```

or

```
return std::unique_ptr<nts::cInput>(new nts::cInput(val));
```

Comment: I think this doesnt create a new object nts::cInput, how could it be without invoking the constructor or using the "new" keyword ?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique std::make_unique<T> "Constructs an object of type T and wraps it in a std::unique_ptr." It allocates the memory and calls the constructor for you, and does it in an exception safe way.

Comment: it seems my function can't find the function, because i got a "no member name 'make_unique' in namespace 'std'"

Comment: @freeinternet - What C++ standard are you using?

Comment: not sure about that but with the update version (the 2) i got a : no viable conversion from 'unique_ptr<nts::cInput>' to 'unique_ptr<nts::IComponent>'

Comment: It should work, have a look here: https://godbolt.org/z/gTnywE Are you sure you have included the needed headers and your inheritance is as you've described?

Comment: i got this: https://i.imgur.com/agXH0w3.png for return (std::make_unique<nts::cInput>(val));

Comment: Again, it should work, see here: https://godbolt.org/z/PBPDqp Are you _SURE_ your inheritance hierarchy is as you've said?

Comment: @freeinternet A `unique_ptr<nts::cInput>` *can* be assigned to a `unique_ptr<nts::IComponent>`, but only if `nts::cInput*` is implicitly convertible to `nts::IComponent*`, ie `nts::cInput` derives from `nts::IComponent`, which is true in the code provided in your question, but if it is not working in your real code, then your real code does not match your question's code.

Comment: I'm 100% sure for the hierarchy, and this code output wiht g++ this: https://i.imgur.com/T5iPBbg.png, also IComponent is an interface, and AbsComponent an abstract classes.

Comment: Can you copy & paste here the class & inheritance definitions you have, just to confirm? Just the class names/inheritance, not the bodies/members, no need for that.

Comment: You said you have `class cInput : public AbsComponent`, but in reality you have `class cInput : AbsComponent`. If you want this to work, you will have to inherit from `AbsComponent` publicly. If you don't, std::unique_ptr has no way of knowing that it is allowed to cast `cInput*` to `AbsComponent*`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance (if you are not aware, class inheritance is private by default, so you need to explicitly ask for it to be public)

Comment: thank you very much, making huge mistakes as i'm tired!!